# Save cache key to all memcached backend

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, memcached

I have 3 EC2 Server what a connected with the ELB from Amazon. On all three I have installed memcached

```
'LOCATION': [
    '172.19.26.240:11211',
    '172.19.26.242:11211',
    '172.19.26.246:11211',
]
```

How I can save in all memcached the same information from the cache key.
Currently I use `cache.set()`

```
    cache.set(self.cache_key, {
        'length': self.content_length,
        'uploaded': 0
    })
```

Can can share somehow the cache over the three server? or exist something for Django for it?

Because if I do cache.get(self.cache_key) I get sometimes data and sometimes no data what not happen on a single memcache instance.

EDIT: Problem was the memcached instances was not knowing each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code already does exactly what you want. Memcached replicates the cache over the different servers.